# Outputting an image summary to Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to visualize the filters of a convolutional layer using [this code](https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5), but cannot get the image to write to my summary file.  I have scalars that I am outputting with no issue, and I attempted to modify the code to add the image as follows

```
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='Perf/Reward', simple_value=float(mean_reward))
summary.value.add(tag='Perf/Length', simple_value=float(mean_length))
with tf.variable_scope(self.name + "/conv1", reuse=True):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights")
    grid = put_kernels_on_grid(weights)
    image = tf.summary.image('conv1/weights', grid, max_outputs=1)
    summary.value.add(tag='conv1/weights', image=image)
self.summary_writer.add_summary(summary, episode_count)
```

With only the scalars, this works fine, but adding the image gives the error

```
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected Image got Tensor. for field Value.image
```

I also tried adding the image summary directly by changing the code to

```
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='Perf/Reward', simple_value=float(mean_reward))
summary.value.add(tag='Perf/Length', simple_value=float(mean_length))
with tf.variable_scope(self.name + "/conv1", reuse=True):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights")
    grid = put_kernels_on_grid(weights)
    image = tf.summary.image('conv1/weights', grid, max_outputs=1)
    self.summary_writer.add_summary(image, episode_count)
self.summary_writer.add_summary(summary, episode_count)
```

But got the error

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'
```

What is the correct way to output my image to my summary file?

Answer (score 1):

<s>`put_kernels_on_grid` is returning a tensor; by 'image' I think the author just means that you can print it out to see what the kernel looks like.  Try using `tf.summary.tensor_summary`.</s>

Whoops, sorry.  I have been able to save a tensor as an image using the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_xs = np.ones((100, 100, 1)) * 200
init = tf.constant(batch_xs, dtype=tf.uint8)
grid = tf.get_variable('var_name', dtype=tf.uint8, initializer=init)

encoded_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(grid)

fwrite = tf.write_file("junk.jpeg", encoded_image)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(fwrite)
```

However `tf.image.encode_jpeg` still returns a tensor with DataType string, so `tf.summary.image` won't accept it.  The code you're working from predates TensorFlow 1.0, so it's definitely not going to work as written.

Hopefully this helps somewhat.

Comment: The example code given outputs the summary to Tensorboard though.  tf.summary.image() takes a Tensor and outputs a Summary protocol buffer, so it should work with the summary writer.

Comment: I tried this method, and it is mostly working, but I am having another issue where my output images are the same every time even though I know my weights are changing (I have another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725080/tf-get-variable-not-returning-changed-weights) detailing it.  Is there something extra I have to do in order to make it re-evaluate the new weights every time I print it out, since I'm trying to watch how it changes over time?