# tf.get_variable() not returning changed weights

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a program where I set up a neural network in Tensorflow that has convolutional layers and I'm trying to periodically output the filter weights as an image.  I know my network is updating correctly based on the performance I'm tracking in Tensorboard (and I've validated that the weights are changing by printing them directly), but the weights image is always the same (seemingly random) values.  I initialize my layers using

```
self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, s_size], dtype=tf.float32)
self.image_in = tf.reshape(self.inputs, shape=[-1, int(input_pixels / view_width), view_width, 1])
self.conv1 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.elu, inputs=self.image_in, num_outputs=16, kernel_size=[8, 8], stride=[4, 4], padding='VALID', scope="conv1")
self.conv2 = slim.conv2d(activation_fn=tf.nn.elu,  inputs=self.conv1, num_outputs=32, kernel_size=[4, 4], stride=[2, 2], padding='VALID', scope="conv2")
hidden = slim.fully_connected(slim.flatten(self.conv2), 256, activation_fn=tf.nn.elu)
```

And once the training is running, every 100 iterations I save the weights using the functions provided [here](https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5) and

```
filters = ["conv1", "conv2"]
for filter in filters:
    with tf.variable_scope(self.name + "/" + filter, reuse=True):
        weights = tf.get_variable("weights")
        grid = put_kernels_on_grid(weights)
        scipy.misc.imsave('filters/' + filter + "_" + str(episode_count) + ".jpg", grid.eval()[0, :, :, 0])
```

Given that the weights in the filters are correctly updating, why would the weights returned by tf.get_variable() not update as well?

Comment: Are you sure it's not updating? Can you simply evaluate `weights` and print the numbers?

Comment: It is definitely updating, I've printed the values directly and watched them change, and in addition if I add
    

`with tf.variable_scope(self.name + "/conv1_lower", reuse=True):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights")
    summary.value.add(tag='Filter Weight', simple_value=float(weights.eval()[0, 0, 0, 0]))`


then the single weight will plot to Tensorboard and change over time.

Comment: What happens if you print `grid.eval()[0, :, :, 0]` right before the call to `imsave`?  What is the dtype of `grid.eval()[0, :, :, 0]`?  Also, are the images actually the same?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue. Even I am facing this issue